# Distribution function of $-\min(X,0)$

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

Given $Z = -\min(X,0)$, with $X$ having distribution function $F$. Find the distribution function of $Z$.

**My attempt** If $P(X>0) = 0$, then $Z=-X$. Thus, the  cdf$(Z)$ $= 1 -$ $F_{X}(-x)$. Now, if $P(X>0) > 0$, then $P(Z = 0) = P(X\geq 0) = 1- F_{X}(0)$. Finally, for $x>0$, $P(Z\leq x) = P(-\text{min}(X,0)\leq x) = P(0\geq X\geq -x) = P(X\geq -x) - P(X\geq 0) = F_{X}(0) - F_{X}(x)$

Thus, we conclude that $F_{X^{-}}(x) = F_{X}(0) - F_{X}(-x)$ ($x\geq 0$), and $ F_{X^{-}}(x) = 1-F_{X}(-x)$  ($x\leq 0$).

**My question** Is the conclusion above correct? Or did I mess up on the part regards to $x> 0$? If I did, please help correct it if you could. Would really appreciate any input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inspirationally I will state how I would approach such a problem (I assume that F is continuous):

(i) The minimum makes it natural to consider three cases: $z<0$, $z=0$ and $z\geq 0$.

(ii) For $z<0$ then $P(Z\leq z)= 0$ as $\min{(0,X)}\geq 0$ almost surely.

(iii) $P(Z=0) = P(-\min{(0,X)} = 0) = P(X\geq 0) = 1-F(0)$.

(iv) For $z>0$, $P(Z>z)=P(X < -z) = F(-z)$ such that $P(Z\leq z) = 1 - F(-z)$.

(v) All in all, $P(Z\leq z)=0$ for $z<0$ and $P(Z\leq z)= 1-F(-z)$ for $z\geq 0$.

Comment: Are you sure with the final conclusion? For $z<0$, I don't think $P(Z\leq z)=0$;( It's clear that there exists infinite values of $X$ to make this probability not equal $0$, isn't it?

Comment: Keep in mind the definition of $Z$ is $-$min$(X,0)$.

Comment: What value of $X$ would yield a negative $Z$-value?

Comment: None. I'm dumb:( My apology. I think your solution is correct then.

Comment: You shouldn't apologise. But I'm contemplating, why this clearly is troubling us a lot. I myself started out with msm's solution but changed my mind. I'll maybe return with some insight later.

Comment: Just looked at your answer, and right at the beginning it is false. (ii) is obviously false since $Z$ can have negative values when $X>0$. Please correct.

Comment: Please give an example of a value of $X$ and the corresponding $Z$-value, where $Z$ is negative.

Comment: msm: I can see, that you have deleted your solution. Does this mean, that you verify mine?